# AuthenticationActivity has leaked window org.chromium.content.browser.input.PopupTouchHandleDrawable

Tags: android, azure, adal

Does anyone have experience with Azure on Android. Having a this problem all the time.

I am experiencing this in my app, but also got it when I tried to build the sample app. Details here:

[Azure Sample Question](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android/issues/9)

Comment: seems like a popup is not being dismissed prior to `onDestroy` of its parent.

Comment: Yes, however AuthenticationActivity is not something I have access to.

Comment: If it's in a library or framework there is nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: For issues with ADAL Android please file an issue here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues

Comment: @RichRandall issue created https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/433